# Make tabbar item pop viewcontroller like instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tabbarViewController with 5 item.
[image]

I want to make the 3rd item pop to a new ViewController (like Instagram's take Image button), so in tabbarController class, I use **UITabbarDelegate** with **tabBar:didSelectItem** method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
CreateViewController *dest = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CreateNewRecipe"];
if (item.tag == 1) {
    [self presentViewController:dest animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But in the view controller that I presented to, when I **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:** (In button action) to get back, it's turn back to **"NaviOfCreateViewController"**:

[image]

I just want it's turn back to the TabbarController that before I click the 3rd Tabbar Item. Any solution to help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I sloved my problem, I use an UITabbar outlet into a view controller and customize it my own.
And of course using **UITabbarDelegate** with **tabBar:didSelectItem** method